# Multidimensional Tiff as Tensorflow Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tiff

I want to put a tiff stack of 23 images as an input to a Tensorflow model.
Unfortunatelythe tensorflow_io library can't handle Tensorflow stacks.
Is there any other way to do it?

The model is use looks like:

```
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(Conv3D(1,
                     kernel_size=(1,1,3),
                     padding='valid',
                     input_shape=(img_width,img_height,23,1),
                     data_format='channels_last',
                     activation='relu'
                    )
             )
    model.add(Conv3D(8,
                     kernel_size=(1,1,3),
                     padding='valid',
                     input_shape=(img_width,img_height,21,1),
                     data_format='channels_last',
                     activation='relu'
                    )
             )
    
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,1,2),
                           padding='valid')
             )
    
    model.add(Conv3D(8,
                     kernel_size=(1,1,3),
                     padding='valid',
                     input_shape=(img_width,img_height,9,1),
                     data_format='channels_last',
                     activation='relu'
                     )
             )
    model.add(Conv3D(16,
                     kernel_size=(1,1,3),
                     padding='valid',
                     input_shape=(img_width,img_height,7,1),
                     data_format='channels_last',
                     activation='relu'
                    )
             )
    
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    
    model.add(Conv3D(1,
                     kernel_size=(1,1,5),
                     padding='valid',
                     input_shape=(img_width,img_height,5,1),
                     data_format='channels_last',
                     activation='sigmoid'
                    )
             )
    
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling3D())
```

Comment: Kindly avoid unnecessary introductions (edited out); the fact that you "*have struggled quiet hard for the last few days*" is irrelevant to the question, and absolutely useless both for possible respondents and for future visitors. Please keep your posts uncluttered,  concise, and to the point.

Comment: okay. sorry for that

Comment: No problem, just keep it in mind for the future please